# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError при запуске jar файла сделанного в maven

Tags: java, исключения, консоль, jar

Как можно решить проблему с вылетом NoClassDefFoundError?
При запуске в Idea всё работает нормально и не кидает такого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это при запуске

C:\Computer\Programming\task3\target>java -cp task3.jar;java_simple_1.1.jar com.exsposit.practica.Main

> Error: A JNI
>   error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 7 more

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста. ен могли бы удалить картинку и приложить все в виде текста? 
расскажите как вы из идеи запускаете?

Comment: java_simple_1.1.jar -> json_simple_1.1.jar

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что когда IDEA запускает программу, она контролирует наличие в `CLASSPATH` всех необходимых зависимостей. Когда вы запускаете, это придётся делать вам самому. Положите рядом с вашим jar-файлом файл [java-json.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) и укажите Java, что в нём нужно искать классы

```
java -cp task3.jar;java-json.jar com.example.MainClass
```

Comment: не помогло или я что-то не так написал?

Comment: Вроде всё, что нужно написали. В java_simple_1.1.jar точно есть каталоги org/json/simple/parser?

Comment: Добавил скриншот в посте выше, проверьте